# What happens when I write to a memory-mapped register?

Tags: microcontroller, avr

I'm trying get familiar with AVR microcontrollers. I am a bit confused on how memory-mapped registers actually function.

I am using avr-libc and programming in C. Looking at avr-libc sources, there are many internal registers which are accessed by writing/reading SRAM locations. When I write to a register's memory location, does that byte in SRAM actually get overwritten, then asyncronously copied into the register?

Thanks!

Comment: Some mailing addresses are apartments, some ar buildings, some are post office boxes.  And if you notice on many streets house numbers will be skipped the even side will step by 4s instead of 2s.  A relatively small percentage of the address space is sram, some percentage is flash, some percentage is peripheral control registers.  and some percentage there is nothing there.  Unlike an x86 which there is a historical reason for what happened, a normal memory space design will not have these things collide.

Comment: for a peripheral when you write to a control register you are talking to that control register on an MCU like this there isnt an SRAM location there also.  Now some peripherals the control registers might happen to be implemented with a very small sram that that logic uses.  else they are implemented with flip flops or have no storage at all.  depends on the peripheral and that control register.

Comment: unfortunately avr is as bad as x86 for a first time system to try to understand this as there are different address spaces and addressing modes or access modes that have overlapping addresses.  but just think of this as 123 main street vs 123 grand street.  rather than 456 main street being sram and 789 main street being a uart control register.

Comment: Don't think of hardware registers as memory, think of reading or writing such a register as a function call to the hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: it depends.

The long answer: when you write to a memory mapped register in C, the compiler emits the same instructions as you would any other memory access (load/store/move/etc). The processor would perform a memory access to the address as it would normally do, in the case of a write it would write the address of the register to the internal bus, enable the write strobe, and then output the desired data on the data lines of the bus.

This is where it gets complicated. The output data may get routed to any other circuit in the MCU: it could indeed be stored in an SRAM structure or a FIFO, but it may simply be latched or “registered” by latches and flip flops, or it could even simply be routed somewhere without being stored. In most cases the write is likely synchronously registered (which may or may not be an SRAM), but that’s not guaranteed and it’s best to check the data sheet or reference manual of your particular chip on the particular registers you’re interested in.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unlikely that every special function register (SFR) actually has what could be considered a byte in SRAM.  Many registers have unimplemented bits, or have read-only bits, or bits that you clear by writing a 1, or do something totally special when you read or write from them.  The chip designers would need custom circuitry to implement all these behaviors.  Putting an actual byte of RAM in front of that would just add complication and cost.

Just because you can read and write from RAM and SFRs using the same set of AVR instructions, it doesn't imply that there is any similarity in how those two types of memory store their data.  It's more likely that they are just two different types of devices connected to the same bus.

However, we can never really tell because the silicon design of the AVR chips is not open source.  You'll get more accurate answers if you ask about something that can be tested, like "how many cycles does it take for a write to such-and-such register to have an effect".

Comment: The OP wrote "many internal registers which...", not "every special function register". And AVR does not put a byte of ram "in front" of a register. It's all about addressing, and you should know why is so.

Answer (score -1):

> When I write to a register's memory location, does that byte in SRAM actually get overwritten, then asyncronously copied into the register?

The byte in SRAM is actually overwritten; the register simply reflects the change immediately. And viceversa.

You can think at those register as an alias for a SRAM location. Or you can think at those SRAM locations as *rooms* with two *doors* - one from a corridor (the SRAM bus), and one from another corridor (the register names).

The CPU uses different instructions to access the same location, depending on the addressing mode specified, but in the end the same location is accessed. As the CPU executes one instruction at a time, there is no "asynchronous" mechanism; either way, the location is modified and the next CPU instruction sees the new value.

Still another way to see this, is to think at two different data spaces, partly overlapped.

Why is it so? Because it can be handy to be able to refer many registers in a loop, for example. There are many register and, if you want to save them all, you can implement that with a loop addressing SRAM instead that using many instructions to indicate each register in turn.

You can also google for that, for example I've found this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/165321/avr-why-io-registers-have-io-addresses-and-sram-adresses

Comment: Most peripherals aren't in SRAM at all - just the same address space. A rare exception is the dual port buffer RAM for the USB peripheral.

Comment: @YannVernier I talk about R0..R31, see this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDGKi.png from the link I posted in my answer. Of course it is a matter of address space, but how you call something that has an address, it is readable and writable, does not have side effects, and does not retain values after a power off? Is it not RAM or SRAM? :-) It is easy (and correct, and convenient sometimes) to think at R0..R31 as aliases to those RAM locations.

Comment: We call them a register file. The SRAM is a physical block containing nothing but memory, typically in a 2D array, frequently single port (either read or write each cycle). R0..R31 are the CPU's general purpose register file, which you can typically read in multiple places and write simultaneously; for instance MUL reads 2 registers and writes 2 registers in one cycle, which is impossible for the SRAM. SRAM meanwhile takes less silicon area and power for a given amount of data.

Comment: @YannVernier I would VERY pleased to see an answer by you on this topic. Perhaps with some programming example: there is always something to learn from who knows better.

Comment: @YannVernier: The storage for a CPU register file is normally made of [SRAM cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory#Design), with multiple read and write ports. It's very plausible that AVR's "register file" truly is the first 32 cells of a larger SRAM array which form the start of memory address-space.  (IDK if it's possible to have just part of it be multi-ported without paying that complexity cost for the whole thing.  If not, then probably addresses are decoded to figure out which block of physical storage to access.)